# Using std::endl vs "\n" when cin and cout are untied

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

[Fast I/O](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fast-io-for-competitive-programming/) recommends the use of following two line during programming competitions to speed up IO:

```
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); 
    cin.tie(NULL);
```

I can understand removal of sync. But after untying cin and cout how do I ensure that the buffer doesn't get overflowed, cin and cout work properly without blocking and buffer gets flushed properly when I am not using std::endl. Does the use of "\n" automatically handles it?

Comment: The whole point of buffer is that it will get flushed when it's about to get full. You can force flushing using `std::flush()` or `std::endl()`, but if you don't, it will be handled automatically.

Comment: Not sure what the confusion is. `cin` is tied with `cout` so that `cout << "Some message";  cin >> some_value;` will display the message `Some message` to the user before asking for `some_value` (Otherwise, you might get something like `Some m` before waiting for input). There won't be any buffer overflows if cin/cout are untied.

Comment: In a programming competition you're not dealing with interactive user input or prompts. It doesn't really matter how soon output is printed as long as it's printed at all.

Comment: .. and if anyone comes here reading this afterwards: You almost *never* want `std::endl;` ... but If you do - you are in *serious* logging business. In 9999/10000 of all cases - you'd just slowd down  applications, including your one, by using `std::endl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how do I ensure that the buffer doesn't get overflowed,

The output buffer doesn't "overflow". When it gets full, it is automatically flushed, i.e. its contents are written out and its length is reset to 0. This is the case whether `cin` / `cout` are tied or not.

> cin and cout work properly without blocking

You normally want operations on `cin` / `cout` to block. But again, blocking vs. non-blocking I/O has nothing to do with whether `cin` / `cout` are tied.

> and buffer gets flushed properly when I am not using std::endl. Does the use of "\n" automatically handles it?

Outputting `'\n'` only flushes the buffer if the stream is in line-buffered mode. `cout` is automatically put in line-buffered mode if output goes to a terminal; otherwise it is block buffered (i.e. it only gets flushed when it runs full).

In a programming competition `cout` usually goes to a pipe or log file, so it will be block buffered and `'\n'` doesn't cause a flush. However, in that situation it also doesn't matter whether prompts are displayed before input is read (which is the normal use case for tied `cin` / `cout`). Just make sure you produce the right output and let the I/O library worry about buffering. The buffer is automatically flushed when it runs full, when the stream is closed, and when your program exits. No output is lost (unless your program crashes, but then you have other things to worry about).

Comment: So can I assume that If I untie cin from cout in a non-interactive environment the inputs and outputs in my program will be handled in the right order without any flushing problems?